# C-string appender for buffers and strings

Tags: performance, c, strings, type-safety

Is this C appender safe, and reasonably optimal?

```
#define REALLOC_BUFFER_SIZE 4096

char *append(char *orig_str, size_t *orig_str_size, const char *append_str) {
    // no action required if appending an empty string
    if (append_str[0] == 0) {
        return orig_str;
    }

    // does the current char* have enough space?
    size_t req_space = strlen(orig_str) + strlen(append_str) + 1; // +1 for NULL byte

    // resize if the required space is greater than the original buffer size.
    if (req_space > *orig_str_size) {
        // prepare the variable with the amount of space we want
        size_t allocate = *orig_str_size + req_space + REALLOC_BUFFER_SIZE;

        char *new_str = (char *)realloc(orig_str, allocate);
        // resize success.. 
        if (new_str == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't reallocate memory\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        // the realloc didn't fail, here is our new pointer
        orig_str = new_str;

        // overwrite the free space with NULL's
        memset(orig_str + strlen(orig_str), 0, req_space);

        // copy the appending text to the string
        strcpy(orig_str + strlen(orig_str), append_str);

        // modify the original size
        *orig_str_size = allocate;

    } else {
        // append the string
        strcpy(orig_str + strlen(orig_str), append_str);
    }

    return orig_str;
}
```

Example usage:

```
char *buffer;
size_t buffer_size = 20;
int i;

buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer_size);
strcpy(buffer, "1234567890123456789"); // fill some data prior.. 

// original string
for (i=1; i < 100; ++i) {
    buffer = append(buffer, &buffer_size, "AABBCC");
}

free(x);
```

Latest changes: [GitHub](https://github.com/mikecurry74/buffer_manager)

Comment: In your title, please **only** state the function/purpose of your code; the body of your post is where the questions should go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what the other answers say and I generally agree with:

Don't call `strlen` more than once.  That's just a waste.  Count the length of `orig_str` and `append_str` once at the beginning of the function and store them away in `const` variables.  That will also make your initial check whether `append_str` is empty look cleaner:

```
const size_t append_len = strlen(append_str);
if (!append_len)
    return orig_str;
const size_t orig_len = strlen(orig_str);
```

Moving the `strlen(orig_str)` above the conditional would look cleaner in my eyes but it might be a pessimization if `append_str` is often empty.

Of course, the most efficient way would be if you could pass `orig_len` as an additional input parameter.  Or you could use a

```
struct string_buffer
{
  size_t length;
  size_t capacity;
  char * data;
};
```

that encapsulates all the required info and change your function's signature to

```
ssize_t
append_string(struct string_buffer * buffer, const char * appendix);
```

where the function could return the number of bytes successfully appended or –1 on error.

My second remark would be that you are growing your buffer by a constant amount each time you reallocate.  It should really grow exponentially unless you really know that linear growth will be preferable in your specific use-case, which I find hard to imagine how that could be.

Concerning your comments: there is no `NULL` byte.  `NULL` is a macro constant for the *null pointer*.  The *null byte* is abbreviated as `NUL` in the ASCII character set.  I would also find it helpful to have your function's semantics exactly documented in a comment.  For example, should the user free the buffer if it fails and returns `NULL`?  Will the existing data be modified in that case?  I can try answering those questions by reading your implementation but that doesn't allow me to distinguish a bug in your code from a different valid design decision.

Answer (score 4):

- `strcat(orig_str, append_str)` looks cleaner than a `strcpy/strlen` combo.
- `memset` is pointless. You need only 1 terminating zero, and it is taken care of by string routines.
- The responsibilities of `if (req_space > *orig_str_size)` and a corresponding `else` clauses overlap. The only task of the `if` clause should be string reallocation. Copying needs to be performed in any case. Consider instead

  ```
  if (req_space > *orig_str_size) {
      allocate = ...;
      char *new_str = realloc(orig_str, allocate);
      if (new_str == NULL) {
          handle_error;
      }
      *orig_str_size = allocate;
      orig_str = new_str;
  }
  strcat(orig_str, append_str);
  ```
- `fprintf` doesn't belong to a such low level routine. Returning an error condition is enough. It is up to the caller to print or not to print.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

> ```
> char *new_str = (char *)realloc(orig_str, allocate);
> ```

has a problem:

1. In C, do not cast the returned value from `realloc` (and family).

---

In this line, from the usage example:

> ```
> buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer_size);
> ```

there are a couple of problems:

1. In C, do not cast the returned value from `malloc` (and family).
2. Always check the returned value (`!= NULL`) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing about this function that bugs me. If a realloc happens, the `orig_str` is invalidated. That goes against my expectation of parameters passed to functions. Instead of returning the new `char *`, how about changing the pointer to `char ** pOrig_str` so it can be modified in-place?